# Accessing DOM APIs in Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox extension, which is doing two things (for the context of this question):

1. Registering for certain DOM events, viz `DOMContentLoaded` and `DOMFrameContentLoaded`.
2. In the call back for the events, access the DOM APIs and do certain operations.

The extension gets the first event (either `DOMContentLoaded` or `DOMFrameContentLoaded`), and the callback function invokes some DOM APIs. I am observing, before the call returning back to my extension from the DOM API call, another event firing and my call back function getting invoked (I haven't been able to narrow down which specific DOM API, as my extension invokes bunch of DOM APIs).

Is this even possible? BTW, I am on Firefox 12 on Windows. I am printing the `threadManager.isMainThread`, and in both situations the event call back is being invoked on the main thread.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is generally single-threaded. However, this doesn't mean that functions cannot be reentered (a function calling itself being the most obvious example). So an event handler could still be called while another event handler is executing. AFAICT this can happen under the following conditions:

- The event handler causes (directly or indirectly) another event to be generated and dispatched. In particular, DOM manipulations will cause mutation events - the processing of such events happens synchronously. E.g. calling `element.setAttribute()` will create `DOMAttrModified` event and that event will be processed before `element.setAttribute()` returns, including running event handlers.
- The event handler is "paused". This will typically happen if a modal dialog (like `alert()`) is opened - the current event handler will wait for this dialog to be closed while other event handlers can still be triggered. A less common case is the usage of the [`yield` keyword in generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Generators).
- The event handler calls [nsIThread.processNextEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIThread#processNextEvent%28%29). This call might execute event handlers associated with the next event in the queue. Technically, this point is the same as the one before it - `alert()` will call `nsIThread.processNextEvent()` internally to ensure that events are processed while the caller is blocked.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir for the answer. I am not doing directly any of the things you mention. In my extension I am registering for DOMContentLoaded and DOMFrameContentLoaded. In my test case I am seeing that DOMContentLoaded gets fired, and in my handler I am invoking some DOM APIs to READ data and before they return, DOMFrameContentloaded gets invoked. I'm not causing (atleast directly) to cause those events to be invoked while I am in the middle of processing. Do you know if any DOM APIs internally invokes processNextEvent() before returning? If yes, anyway to suppress that behavior?

Comment: No, AFAIK the only things to invoke `processNextEvent()` internally are modal dialogs and synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Thanks again. BTW, the test page I am using has inline Java applet, could that be code path where Firefox internally does processNextEvent()? Where in the Firefox code base can I look to verify that?

Comment: You can search the code [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/). I am unsure whether communicating with a Java applet would spin the event loop - but it is possible given that plugins run in a separate process and communication with them is asynchronous (but needs to appear synchronous for LiveConnect to work).